# MongoDB select by nested data

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to query nested data in MongoDB.

Ideally I would like to run a query similar to:

```
SELECT FROM attributes.type1 WHERE value = true
```

I understand that I can use [dot notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29) to query by attributes.type1, but is it possible to query deeper than this?

Thanks!

My data set:

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "type1": [
            {
                "year": "2012",
                "value": "true"
            },
            {
                "year": "1998",
                "value": "false"
            }
        ],
   }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can query by `db.collection.find({"attributes.type1.year": 2012})`
or for example use advanced queries like: `db.collection.find({"attributes.type1.year": {$lt: 2000}})`.

Is this what you mean?